# Sorting Lunch Items Stored as Hash Values

Tags: ruby, hash, iteration

Can you please help me figure this out?

> Write the code necessary to print JUST the values of each key-value
>   pair in lunch_order. (Use puts instead of print so each value is
>   printed on its own line.)

**Code**

```
lunch_order = 
{ "Ryan" => "wonton soup",
  "Eric" => "hamburger",
  "Jimmy" => "sandwich",
  "Sasha" => "salad",
  "Cole" => "taco"
}
```

Hint:
For example, you should print out

```
wanton soup
hamburger
and so on.
```

Meaning: each y-value should be on its own line

I have tried various syntax but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Can someone please explain the right way to approach this problem? I would greatly appreciate it.

---

#### My Solution

I figured out the answer: create a y_value array and then use each method on it. For example:

```
y_value = ["wonton soup", "hamburger", "sandwich", "salad", "taco"]
y_value.each { |x| puts "#{x}" }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'll not do your home work.  `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.` If you try and have doubts about the output, I advise you to open another question.

Comment: Hi fotanus! I figured out the answer ... I had to create an array of y-values and then use each loop on it. Sorry I wasn't too clear when asking the first question.

Comment: if you found a solution to your problem, answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: @MsUzoAgu oh, you were clear. This is a homework question, though, which is what fotanus was pointing out. Also, your solution, though it works, is very much not ideal. Look at the documentation for Ruby's Hash class.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for letting me know that I can answer my own question and also accept my answer! Just tried doing that but was told that I have to wait 7 hours to answer my own question because I have less than 10 reputation points. I have updated the question above to reflect solution. Thank you:)

Comment: Hi guys! I only started studying ruby (on my own) like 3 days ago and the question isn't a homework question per say (it is an exercise question that I can skip (no penalties). Will look at ideal way of answering the question on my 2nd go round. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A More Idiomatic Solution

Your solution doesn't sort the values. There are certainly many ways to solve this problem, but the following is both short and idiomatic:

```
lunch_order.values.sort.each { |lunch| puts lunch }
```

This will send the following to standard output:

> hamburger
>   salad
>   sandwich
>   taco
>   wonton soup

Comment: Thank you for providing feedback:)

Comment: Your feedback is AWESOME! Not only do I know to add "values" to get my y-values but also now I know what adding "sort" does to my code. Thank you:)